# Verifying the integral solution: $I= \int \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1+2\cos x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate:
>   $$
> I= \int \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1+2\cos x}}dx
> $$

I got an answer which does not match the keys section of the book I'm solving and want to verify which one is correct.

Start by recalling:
$$
\cos 2x = \cos^2 x-\sin^2 x
$$
Therefore:
$$
\sqrt{1+2\cos x} =\sqrt{1+\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x} = \sqrt{2\cos^2 x} = \sqrt2|\cos x|
$$

Thus:
$$
I = \int \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt2 |\cos x|}dx
$$

Substitute $t=\cos x$, then $dt = -\sin x dx$, $dx = - {dt\over \sin x}$, hence:
$$
I = -{1\over \sqrt 2}\int \frac{dt}{|t|} = \boxed{-{\text{sgn}(\cos x)\over \sqrt 2}\ln(|\cos x|)+C}
$$

While the answer section suggests:
$$
I = -\sqrt{1+2\cos x} + C
$$

Which one is correct?

Comment: $2\cos x\ne\cos 2x$

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio what a silly mistake, thanks for pointing this out to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $u=1+2\cos{x}$

$\frac{-1}{2}du=\sin{x}dx$

So the integral becomes $$\frac{-1}{2}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}du=-\sqrt{u}+c$$